# Are digital arts on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Clearly, drawing and painting are very on-topic here, being arts.

Are their computer equivalents (i.e. with graphics tablets, etc) on-topic here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The impression that I've often received is that this is a site for handmade arts and crafts.

If it's a general art or craft concept, I say keep it.

But if it's *How do I work this tool, or do so and so online or in photoshop?" No.

Therefore, I would recommend that you move these over to Graphic Design.

Answer (score 11):

## I think it would be fine but.....

I think that depends on the specific topic at hand. There is a [Graphic Design SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) already that might be a better fit for most questions about the tools and techniques. Cross posting is not forbidden but I think depending on the question you might find more expertise there.

Questions about the art itself might be more on topic here but then you might be bordering on opinion based answers and those would be off topic.

In any case there is little harm in asking and one could always ask here in meta first or in chat if they are not sure.

Comment: I would agree that "it depends."  For example, I don't feel like there is a huge digital illustration community on [GD.SE](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com), so some related questions might work well here.  However, if your question is "How do I achieve [specific effect] in [specific application]?" the question might be a good fit on graphic design.

Comment: I agree, I tend to I think graphic design is generally well-suited to the digital arts, but it's a fine line.

Comment: Objective questions about the art could well be on topic, such as on improving shading techniques, etc. However they may veer more towards a Fine Arts or simply Art stack exchange's domain.

Answer (score 6):

I'm a member of the [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) site, here to offer some clarification for our site. Digital arts is totally on topic at GD, we'd welcome any questions that you might deem off topic in that area.

We *do* have some restrictions, though... Regarding the following thoughts from JTL and Zizouz212

> But if it's *How do I work this tool, or do so and so online or in photoshop?" ...  I would recommend that you move these over to Graphic Design.

and

> However, if your question is "How do I achieve [specific effect] in [specific application]?" the question might be a good fit on graphic design.

These types of questions make up the majority of our site. Unfortunately, they are often some of the lowest quality questions that we see as well. To try and elevate the quality, we require that the user shows what they've tried. This is such a common problem that we use one of our custom close reasons for it:

> If you're asking for help with implementation, please include what you've tried and why it didn't work with screenshots. Please edit your post with what your desired results are, what resources you referenced and why those didn't work. See [this](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/699/8708) meta post for discussion and see [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) post on how to ask a good question.

Basically, we try to avoid "tutorial on demand" type questions such as "*Never used Photoshop before, how can I paint a painting [like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mona_Lisa,_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci,_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg)? Step by step instructions would be appreciated!*" We welcome beginners as much as experts, but we maintain an expectation that you put some effort into researching your task before posting a question.

So, if you see a question along those lines and think it would be a good candidate for GD, please keep that in mind! It's never a nice experience for the user for a question to get migrated then closed on the target site. If the question could use some improvement, I would suggest a comment along the lines of:

> `Hello, welcome to the community! Your question would be a better fit for [graphicdesign.se]'s scope. I recommend asking over there, but be sure to include what you've tried so far so that your question fits [their guidelines](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)`

Also, if you're unsure if a question is a worthy candidate for GD, feel free to pop in to [our chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) and ask someone. We're friendly!

Comment: Welcome to A&C, and thanks for the answer!