# Does use of a computer to create art put it under Graphic Design SE?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Rather than using brushes to paint an artwork on canvas, someone could capture essentially the same handstrokes on a digital tablet feeding a drawing program, then have the computer print it to create a tangible work.

That can be part of a graphic design workflow, although I'm not sure graphic designers would consider that graphic design.

Such questions are on-topic on Graphic Design SE, and since a digital workflow is probably standard in graphic design, that community would be better-equipped to handle them, making that a logical place to post them.

Our help section explicitly excludes "graphic arts", with a link to Graphic Design SE.  According to the dictionary definitions of graphic arts, that seems to include what we do and has nothing to do with a digital workflow.  So I'm not sure what our Help section means with that reference, other than to suggest that what's on-topic at Graphic Design SE is off-topic here.

However, there is plenty of overlap among SE sites; we typically don't exclude content based on it being on-topic at another site.

I don't recall ever seeing questions here about creating art by digital means, but that could just be because people in our community don't do it, or the questions aren't asked here because Graphic Design SE is a better venue for that.

Is there an explicit scope definition somewhere for our site that excludes art created with a digital workflow?

Comment: If one is making a work of fine art I am not so sure it would fit in with the language of Graphic Design at all. Even if made using the tools we normally associate with Graphic Arts.

Comment: That was my reaction. It looks like the only real connection with Graphic Design SE is that the subject areas are related and that site was already a logical place for software questions.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe we have to be clearer in **what exactly** we exclude from our scope.

As rebusB correctly mentioned, color theory and image composition are aspects of art, regardless of whether it's an oil painting or a digital image. The same applies to the identification of [art](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/11298/6316) or [drawing styles](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/2732/6316) (but please check out any update in [this thread](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/603/is-it-time-to-consider-revisiting-ai-art-in-the-sites-scope)!). We certainly have many questions about these topics here.

We also have questions about [pens that get ignored by a scanner software](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/263/6316) or ways to [transfer a digital drawing to dark paper](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/3527/6316). So the simple fact that an artwork is digital or its creation contained a digital workflow doesn't make it off-topic (unless we actually want it to be).

My instinct is that **the actual usage of software should be off-topic**. The main reasons are that the usage of PhotoShop, Illustrator etc. is covered on other sites and proprietary software (like for specific embroidery machines or Cricut and Peparcura etc.) is not readily available for users if they don't also own the same equipment.

**Questions about art theory should be on topic**, regardless of whether it's applied to a digital or traditional artwork. That includes the aforementioned color theory, composition and art styles.

**All (art-related) questions about physical objects should be on topic**, including objects which creation included digital workflows. If someone asks about preserving paper, it doesn't matter if the paper contains a pencil drawing or a printout of a digital artwork.

That would mean:

- We can teach you about color theory and the golden ratio, but how to set the right color or arrange stuff in any software is off topic.
- We can tell you what properties a path file for a laser cutter or embroidery machine should have, but how to create such a path in your specific software is off-topic.
- We can tell you how a 3D print could help you create your artwork, but not how to create the digital model for the print.
- We can tell you the name of a digital art style, but we won't tell you which brush in Photoshop can recreate the style.
- We can identify the [art style of an AI-created image](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/11298/6316), but we won't help you configure any AI to create any image.

Some examples that are very far in the grey area between on and off topic include [digital certificates for digital artwork](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/3936/6316), [printer settings for bookbinding](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/555/6316), the [weird memory card of an embroidery machine](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/10852/6316), [problems with Pepacura software](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/11071/6316) or the [plotter that doesn't cut exactly on the printed lines](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/8813/6316). I could live with these being closed.

Comment: I think this is a good summary of what the current scope actually is. Mixed feelings on a couple of the Qs you identified at the end. **COAs:** seems off-topic, not necessarily because the Q is about digital, but it isn't about the "making" aspect. **Printer settings:** doesn't give me indigestion; directly supports hand crafting, and likely to be a common Q. It's a general Q on how to do it. All software/hardware Qs aren't specifically off-topic, especially on crafting (wasn't an original focus, and the logic of being supported on Graphic Design doesn't apply). (cont'd)

Comment: **Memory card:** strikes me as fair game if the machine is on-topic. **Pepacura software:** the Q was poorly asked. Pepacura is a common tool for hand crafting 3D objects. Not sure all good Qs about it should be off-topic (whether or not they are now). **Cutting:** if the machine is on-topic, this seems like fair game. (cont'd)

Comment: Computers are increasingly becoming an integral part of the workflows the site covers. The site can become obsolete if it doesn't remain relevant and a resource for the user base. We might want to explore how to include some of the relevant Qs without pushing the site definition too much (some clear logic defining a bigger circle around the pool of topics). Other sites have dealt with the poor Q quality issue by defining more rigorous requirements for Qs.

Comment: Added this to my answer as a question: Why isn't this (https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/6314/what-are-joined-and-unjoined-fonts) considered off-topic when it is unquestionably a Graphics Arts related question? It cannot just about digital workflow.

Comment: @fixer1234 - People are not going to stop making things by hand, even as digital tools replace more aspects of art making. That the hand of the artist is involved may be key to making this call. And maybe there should be an exchange for Digital Work (if there isn't already) as well as Art History (for identifying works etc.)

Comment: @rebusB That's a very good question and I agree that the linked post should be off-topic. The answer is rather simple: we are humans and humans make mistakes or have different opinions. If I saw this as a new question, I would close it, but at the time it was posted, it didn't receive enough close votes but got an answer instead.

Comment: I think all those questions given as bad for the site are dead on except for the bookbinding and only because that one is about a step in a hand crafted product. The others are all specific to a manufacturer (a real problem for the site imo) or involve, relative to hand crafted art, obscure specific technical issues that should be off-topic.

Comment: @Elmy - yeah. That, even if off topic, a question can be easily answered by someone here is both a blessing and a curse when it comes to closing off-topic questions. Been there! And yes, it seems better to provide answers whenever possible since that is what we are here for.

Comment: @rebusB, it isn't that people will stop making things by hand. It's more two aspects. 1. Computer-based tools are becoming integral to handmade workflows. If someone is making on-topic art or craft items and their questions are off-topic here, that's a roadblock. The site is a less-useful resource and there's a tendency to gravitate to other places where they can get all their questions answered. 2. It used to be that art and crafting required training, skill, and a lot of practice, which limited who started and continued with it. (cont'd)

Comment: Computer-based tools are opening the doors for an audience that otherwise wouldn't participate. We exclude that audience if it's off-topic. Your points about the downsides are all valid. I still think we should explore expanding the scope a bit to include some of it, and deal with the issues. re: off-topic questions like your example - I agree with your last comment.

Answer (score 2):

So you are saying the tool used to make a work will exclude it from our discussions of any aspects of the work, regardless of whether the question is tool based or not?

Certainly, with the original intent of the site or its creators, the digital workflow was not compatible, but I am one of the people here who have done extensive work using digital tools. There are plenty of design problems, ideas of composition, color, etc. that the tool used have no bearing on. Are we really going to kick all those ideas, problems and possible solutions just because the artist is using a computer instead of brush?

Editing in some more questions:

- What are the other reasons we might send something to Graphic Design?
- There are people here who are doing laser cutting and 3d printing. That is created via digital means, where do they go?

Edit: But here is a question that is squarely in the realm of Graphic Arts that didn't get flagged: [What are joined and unjoined fonts?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/6314/what-are-joined-and-unjoined-fonts)  Why wouldn't this be considered off topic?

Comment: If you read through the original discussion, Arts & Crafts was so broad a topic area they were looking for logical boundaries. They decided certain topics could neatly be excluded, like photography, performing arts, and digital art. The logic on digital art was mainly that they didn't want to turn this site into yet another computer site with lots of questions on how to use software or computer hardware; that was different from the intended focus and it was already the bread and butter of Graphic Design, so there was a good place for people to go with those questions. (cont'd)

Comment: They needed a definition to launch the site, and it makes a neat boundary, but the community can choose to change it. The intention was to exclude computer & software questions, but other aspects of digitally-created art are on-topic here under the original definitions. They weren't thinking about 3D printing or laser cutting. I've been looking at those (general scope of computer-controlled crafting machines), seeing if we can expand those. I think Joachim has some thoughts on digital art, and is exploring expanding the art definition. You would be a great addition to the discussions.  :-)

Comment: Thanks. I will stick my head in more often. Interested in what Joachim has to say on the topic. Because it certainly is part of Art these days. However it also lives in its own world much like photography (and that is an area that has become very digital). Totally agree that we should _not_ be another help desk for the latest cut of Adobe Illustrator etc... even if the artist is making a mural or something.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Meta discussion from when the site was being defined.  The discussion at [Are digital arts on-topic here?](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/are-digital-arts-on-topic-here) was about a digital workflow.  The decision was made to send those to Graphic Design SE.

An early draft of the help section, [What should our on-topic FAQ contain?](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167/what-should-our-on-topic-faq-contain), had the correct term.  In a later draft, [On-topic FAQ Draft](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232/on-topic-faq-draft), it looks like someone was thinking of the Graphic Design link and made a typo of "graphic arts" instead of "digital art".

Bottom line: yes, digital arts are excluded by design.

Comment: Should we correct the wording in the Help section?

Comment: With changing workflows, new mediums or medium-crossovers, and a much better assortment of (free) software with more intuitive UIs, I'm not so sure that just continuing that older consensus is beneficial. I'll see if I can get a good alternative answer up :)